# $ rspec spec/ not working for me. please help

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I am new to rails and this is stopping me.
I am trying to run rspec spec/ and I get errors.  Can anyone help me?

This is the code I am getting:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.0.a6/lib/rspec/rails/transactional_database_support.rb:33: uninitialized constant Rspec::Core (NameError)
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.0.a6/lib/rspec/rails.rb:1
>       from /Users/Kendall/Sites/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
>       from /Users/Kendall/Sites/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:334:in `load'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:334:in `load_spec_files'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:334:in `map'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:334:in `load_spec_files'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
>       from /usr/bin/rspec:19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> sudo gem update rspec-rails

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an older version of the rspec-rails gem installed. Try updating it (2.1.0 is the current version at the time of writing):

```
gem update rspec-rails
```

**Updated following comments**:

You will need to specify the name of one or more spec files or a directory containing your spec files. For example if your spec files are in a folder called spec then this will run them all:

```
rspec spec
```

In a Rails project using Bundler:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

For more info on the rspec command:

```
rspec -h
```

Comment: i get No examples were matched. Perhaps {:unless=>#<Proc:0x00000001005b7790@/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:53>, :if=>#<Proc:0x00000001005b7970@/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:52>} is excluding everything?


Finished in 0.00003 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

Comment: So you got past the original error and now 'No examples were matched'?

Comment: That would suggest that rspec is working but cannot find your tests.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.  do you have any ideas for what i should do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is late, but for the error:

```
No examples were matched. Perhaps {:unless=>#<Proc:0x00000001005b7790@/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:53>, :if=>#<Proc:0x00000001005b7970@/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:52>} is excluding everything? Finished in 0.00003 seconds 0 examples, 0 failures
```

Like it says, a test wasn't found in your test_spec file. You should add an "it" expression with your test case.